# Finding roots of a non linear equation

Tags: roots, nonlinear-system

Can the roots of the following equation can be found analytically?

$$f(x)=-x+x^2+5sin(x)$$

I'm of course referring to the non trivial one (besides $x=0$).

[image]

Comment: No, only numerically. (unless you baptise some real number just for the occasion :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a transcendental equation and you need a numerical method. Newton method would be the simplest to use.

Graph your function; see where more or less are the roots and stat iterating. It will be quite fast.

**Edit**

From the plot, we can seee that the root is close to $-\frac \pi 2$. So, to get an *approximation*, perform a Taylor expansion around this point. This will give
$$\frac{1}{4} \left(-20+2 \pi +\pi ^2\right)-(1+\pi ) \left(x+\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)+\frac{7}{2} \left(x+\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3\right)$$ which is a quadratic in $\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$. Solve it and you get
$$x_0=-\frac{1}{56} \left(20 \pi-8+\sqrt{4544-320 \pi -160 \pi ^2}\right)\approx -1.76962$$ while the exact solution is $\approx -1.76968$.

Comment: How about perturbation theory, would it be solvable using pen and paper?

Comment: @jarhead. I shall put things.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're asking for a solution using the elementary operations and radicals a *finite* number of times (otherwise, what's the point in the first place since you would want some closed form eventually). We can expand the $\sin$ term as an infinite series of powers and can manipulate it as we like since it converges nicely. But what you want would mean solving a power series (infinite) in *finite* radicals. Clearly you can see that this is impossible.

Thus, you will be best served in using some approximation method, many of which will give you a sufficiently fine approximation to the nonzero root.